# Laravel as REST API - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I create applications on the frontend side Angular but in the backend Laravel. I also created a login controller that returns me a token for Angular which then adds to the request headers and it should work but it returns 401... and I don't know why :/

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;

class AuthController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
        $this->middleware('auth:jwt', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 400);
        }

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
        ]);

        $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

        return response()->json(['token' => $token], 201);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        try {
            if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid credentials'], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Could not create token'], 500);
        }

        return response()->json(['token' => $token]);
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            JWTAuth::invalidate(JWTAuth::getToken());
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Failed to logout'], 500);
        }

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }

}
```

I'm not sure if I'm using the right middleware or if I haven't forgotten some configuration.. but the `login()` method in `AuthController` creates and returns a token the problem is with `UserController` and `getUsers()` because I get 401 method :/

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
        $this->middleware('auth:jwt');
    }

    public function getUsers()
    {
        try {
            JWTAuth::invalidate(JWTAuth::getToken());
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Failed to getUsers()'], 500);
        }

        $users = User::all();
        return response()->json($users);
    }

    public function deleteUser($id)
    {
        try {
            JWTAuth::invalidate(JWTAuth::getToken());
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Failed to deleteUser()'], 500);
        }

        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $user->delete();
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Użytkownik został usunięty']);
    }
}
```

routes/api.php

```
Route::post('register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api', 'auth:jwt']], function () {
    Route::post('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::get('users', [UserController::class, 'getUsers']);
    Route::delete('users/{id}', [UserController::class, 'deleteUser']);
});
```

config/auth.php

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'jwt' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Comment: And did you try to setup correct `APP_URL` in `.env`?

Comment: side note: if assigning middleware to routes, there is no need to re declare them in the controller.

Comment: also is your token single use? you are revoking the token on each request `JWTAuth::invalidate(JWTAuth::getToken());` if you attempt to call `getUsers()` twice of course the second time the middleware will not allow you.

Comment: @JaroslavKlimčík 
it was `APP_URL=http://localhost` so I changed to `APP_URL=http://localhost:4200` but nothing changed further as I refresh the page and call BE (request contains a token in the header) for a list of users it gets 401 :/

Comment: @krisgjika 
oh no, I need a solution with a reusable token because the user can refresh the page...

Comment: So don't revoke the token? If using Sanctum you can set a expiration time for your tokens.

Comment: @krisgjika 
do you have any link to an article where this is well implemented?

Comment: @JanuszFrontEnd'u I don't know what you have implemented already but I would use Sanctum https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum

Comment: Make sure you have added header in the `Accept: application/json` and `Content-Type: application/json`

Answer (score 0):

Will you try this?

```
public function getUsers()
{
    try {
        $token = JWTAuth::getToken();
        $user = JWTAuth::authenticate($token);
        
        $users = User::all();
        return response()->json($users);
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Failed to get users'], 500);
    }
}
```